# How to create an object of NSNotification in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to create an object of NSNotification as say:

```
NSNotification *obj=[[NSNotification alloc]init];
```

but when i create like this i get an exception as 'NSConcreteNotification init: is not allowed'.
How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

From the [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:

> You can create a notification object with the class methods [`notificationWithName:object:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNotification/notificationWithName:object:) or [`notificationWithName:object:userInfo:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNotification/notificationWithName:object:userInfo:). However, you don’t usually create your own notifications directly. The NSNotificationCenter methods [`postNotificationName:object:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:) and [`postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:) allow you to conveniently post a notification without creating it first.

Answer (score 2):

NSNotificationCenter has convenience methods to construct and dispatch notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
               postNotificationName:XYYourNotification
               object:@"someObject"];
```

If you want to use your own notifications, create the notification name extern:

```
extern NSString* const XYYourNotification;
```

and define the actual NSString* in your implementation.
If you use string constants for your notification names, your code is less error-prone to typos.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer but instead of `extern` you should use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` which will be `extern` in Objective-C files or `extern "C"` in Objective-C++ projects should you ever find yourself using them.